# how to use opencv setOpenGlDrawCallback function?

Tags: c++, opengl, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.3.2 library downloaded from OpenCV trunk. I want to use setOpenGlDrawCallback function for displaying OpenGL scene. When I compile the below simple code, I get following errors:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth >= 0 && depth <= CV_32F) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\opengl_interop.cpp, line 736
```

what was wrong for this code?

```
// углы поворота
float angx=55, angy=45;
float angstep=10;

String winname = "opengl";

// opengl callback
void on_opengl(void* param)
{
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslated(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);

    glRotatef( angx, 1, 0, 0 );
    glRotatef( angy, 0, 1, 0 );
    glRotatef( 0, 0, 0, 1 );

    static const int coords[6][4][3] = {
        { { +1, -1, -1 }, { -1, -1, -1 }, { -1, +1, -1 }, { +1, +1, -1 } },
        { { +1, +1, -1 }, { -1, +1, -1 }, { -1, +1, +1 }, { +1, +1, +1 } },
        { { +1, -1, +1 }, { +1, -1, -1 }, { +1, +1, -1 }, { +1, +1, +1 } },
        { { -1, -1, -1 }, { -1, -1, +1 }, { -1, +1, +1 }, { -1, +1, -1 } },
        { { +1, -1, +1 }, { -1, -1, +1 }, { -1, -1, -1 }, { +1, -1, -1 } },
        { { -1, -1, +1 }, { +1, -1, +1 }, { +1, +1, +1 }, { -1, +1, +1 } }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        glColor3ub( i*20, 100+i*10, i*42 );
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            glVertex3d(0.2 * coords[i][j][0], 0.2 * coords[i][j][1], 0.2 * coords[i][j][2]);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

        namedWindow(winname,CV_WINDOW_OPENGL | CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO | CV_GUI_NORMAL );
    setOpenGlDrawCallback(winname.c_str(),on_opengl);**

    while (true)
    {
        char key = (char)waitKey(10);

        if( key == 27 )
            break;

        // вращаем
        switch( key )
        {
        case 'w':
            angx+=angstep;
            break;
        case 's':
            angx-=angstep;
            break;
        case 'a':
            angy+=angstep;
            break;
        case 'd':
            angy-=angstep;
            break;
        }
        // обновить рендер
        imshow(winname, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the exact line in your code that causes this error? Open the debugger and find out. Also, the **point_cloud.cpp** example shows exactly how to use `setOpenGlDrawCallback()`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I hope you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the line

```
imshow(winname, NULL);
```

It seems you want to show the window without displaying an image. But when looking at [`cv::imshow`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_user_interface.html#cv-imshow)'s signtaure this will not work, since it expects a `const cv::Mat&`. So what is probably done is that `NULL` is converted into a `cv::Mat` using one of its constructors, most probably the one expecting a `const IplImage*`. But this image pointer is the null pointer, which makes the constructor fail.